# Schedule a method and... just wait (with a timer and threads)

Tags: c#, timer

I must schedule a method to execute every X minutes. My approach is schedule it in a separate thread, with a timer, and leave main thread... just waiting :)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ScheduleMyProcessEveryXMinutes(5);
        
        //wait
    }
    
    private void ScheduleMyProcessEveryXMinutes(int minutes)
    {
        var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
        var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes);

        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
        {
            MyProcess();
        }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
    }
    
    private void MyProcess()
    {
        //Do my job
    }
```

What is the best way to leave main thread 'waiting', consuming the least resources? I am going to run the program in background

Thanks!

Comment: From the example, it isn't very clear when you actually want the main thread to continue then?

Comment: If you just need to schedule a process to run every so often, maybe consider something like a windows service instead? Otherwise your main method is still going to be waiting for *something*, whether it be a button press, a condition in you app, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not going to do anything else with the main thread, why bother with the timer at all? Your code could just be this:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ScheduleMyProcessEveryXMinutes(5);
}
    
private void ScheduleMyProcessEveryXMinutes(int minutes)
{
    var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes);

    while (true)
    {
        MyProcess();
        Thread.Sleep(periodTimeSpan);
    }
}
```

If you are really concerned about actually *using* the thread when it's not needed (e.g. you'd like to eliminate the `Thread.Sleep()`, you could do the above but using async/await:

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await ScheduleMyProcessEveryXMinutes(5);
}
    
private async Task ScheduleMyProcessEveryXMinutes(int minutes)
{
    var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes);

    while (true)
    {
        MyProcess();
        await Task.Delay(periodTimeSpan);
    }
}
```

If for whatever reason you absolutely must just do it the way you showed the code in your question and you just want the `Main()` method to not return, you can wait an infinite length of time:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ScheduleMyProcessEveryXMinutes(5);
    
    Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Though, if you would use `ManualResetEvent` instead of `Thread.Sleep()` in that last example, then at least there'd be a way for some other code to signal to the `Main()` method to actually wake up and return from the method.

The question is missing some details that would be useful in really understanding the nature of your problem. But the above should cover the various scenarios that might apply in your case.

Comment: My idea is to launch the process every x minutes, regardless of how long it takes to run. Using 'sleep' the process is launched 5 minutes AFTER the previous one ends. I like the Thread.Sleep (System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite) option, but several posts talk so much about not using 'sleep' ... I'll try to use ManualResetEvent, if this way the paused thread consumes less resources. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to unconditionally invoke the method even when the previous invocation hasn't finished yet, that's simple enough. In the second example above, you just replace the call to `MyProcess()` with `Task.Run(MyProcess);`. You can still use async/await for the scheduling; just execute the method elsewhere, so that the timing-related method doesn't have to wait for it.